# linux C++ thread in class

Tags: c++, linux

Hi i want to do the class with method which will start in separate thread after creating class. That how i do that:

```
class Devemu {
int VarInc;

void Increm() {
    for(;;) {
        if (VarInc > 532) VarInc = 0;
        else VarInc++;
    }
}

public:
static void* IncWrapper(void* thisPtr) {
    ((Devemu*) thisPtr)->Increm();
    return NULL;
}
Devemu() {
    VarInc = 0;
}
int Var() {
    return VarInc;
}
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

Devemu* em = new Devemu();
pthread_t thread_id;
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &Devemu::IncWrapper, NULL);


for(int i = 0 ;i < 50; i++) {
printf("%d\n", em->Var());
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I unlike that pthread_create in main and IncWrapper method can i change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can put it in the constructor if you like :

```
class Devemu {
int VarInc;
pthread_t thread_id;

void Increm() {
    for(;;) {
        if (VarInc > 532) VarInc = 0;
        else VarInc++;
    }
}

public:
static void* IncWrapper(void* thisPtr) {
    ((Devemu*) thisPtr)->Increm();
    return NULL;
}
Devemu() {
    VarInc = 0;

    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &Devemu::IncWrapper, NULL);
}
int Var() {
    return VarInc;
}
};
```

Comment: thanks it works, but returns segmentation fault. i added mutex_lock and mutex_trylock it also return segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's better to put the thread creation in the separate member-function like that:

```
class Devemu {

    ...

    void run()
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &Devemu::IncWrapper, NULL);
    }

    ...
};
```

Not actually in ctor, because sometimes you (or anyone who uses your code) can forget that thread created in the ctor and start coding like:

```
Devemu m;
...
Devemu m1;
...
```

creating unnecessary threads just like instances of the class.

Comment: Strangely, but I'm sure there's a reason, the new C++0x threads start running the instant their object is created (or can). Ie, no separate object + 'ok now run' calls.

Comment: Have to be careful not to start it twice ;)

Comment: Hm... Your are right, but what if I want run exactly 2 threads? In case of run() I can do it as follows: `Devemu m; m.run(); ... Devemu m1; m1.run()` without having code in the ctor changed. Anyway I prefer explicit creation of the processes, threads, etc over implicit. It's easy enough to forget such small things, especially if your project is big enough.

Comment: @JDonner: @maverik advice is sound. Boost and c++0x threads start at construction because in their design there is a clear division of responsibilities. The `thread` object does nothing but run the thread. In the example code, if you start the thread at construction, there is no guarantee that the new thread does not enter the function *before* your current thread completes construction, and that is undefined behavior. That will be even more dangerous if the class is polymorphic and the function that is run by the thread makes polymorphic method calls (dynamic dispatch).

Comment: As a matter of fact, I like the C++0x design better (implementing Java Runnable) as compared to the design proposed in the question (extending Java Thread), as it is harder to fail into that particular trap.

Comment: Having to call `run()` is a two-phase initialization. It seems to make your life easier on the surface, but it is a well known anti-pattern...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get working source code you need make next changes:

```
--- so0.cpp     2019-11-04 11:26:11.101984795 +0000
+++ so1.cpp     2019-11-04 11:26:57.108501816 +0000
@@ -1,3 +1,7 @@
+#include "stdio.h"
+#include <pthread.h>
+#include <cstdlib>
+
 class Devemu {
 int VarInc;

@@ -24,7 +28,7 @@

 Devemu* em = new Devemu();
 pthread_t thread_id;
-pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &Devemu::IncWrapper, NULL);
+pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &Devemu::IncWrapper, em);
```

My variant for resolving your problem is :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

class Devemu {
private:
    int VarInc;

    pthread_attr_t attr; /* отрибуты потока */
    pthread_t thread_id;

    void Increm();
public:
    static void* IncWrapper (void* thisPtr);
    Devemu();
    ~Devemu();
    int Var();
};

void Devemu::Increm() {
    while (true) {
        if (VarInc > 532) {  VarInc = 0; } else { VarInc++; }
    }
}

void* Devemu::IncWrapper(void* thisPtr) {
    ((Devemu*) thisPtr)->Increm();
    return NULL;
}

Devemu::~Devemu() {
    pthread_cancel (thread_id);
}

Devemu::Devemu() {
    VarInc = 0;
/// get default value of arrts
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
/// start thread
    pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, &Devemu::IncWrapper, this);

}

int Devemu::Var() {
    return VarInc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Devemu* em = new Devemu();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", em->Var());
        usleep (10);
    }
    delete em;
    usleep (1000);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```